# How can I run a method when the controller first time runs?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

My project is running with an in-memory database and a relational database with Entity Framework Core.

When the controller running the first time, I need to copy some data from the relational database to the in-memory database.

Now I do it like this:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {       
        public TestController()
        {           
            if (IMemoryCache.Get("DatabaseInitialised") == null)
            {               
                IMemoryCache.Set("DatabaseInitialised", true);
                ///Some code to copy the data
            }
        }
}
```

I used an `IMemoryCache` to record whether the data has been copied.

Well, sometimes it only run once and sometimes it will still runs twice or more.

Is there any better way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Your code runs more than once because your if is not synchronized between threads. Using IMemoryCache for storing a simple flag also doesn't make sense to me. I suggest you create a separate service to do the copy of data with thread synchronization inside and inject it into your controller as a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you need, I suggest you use a background service which can be triggered on startup rather than in the controller. You will then be sure that it is run only once. If the service is registered as a singleton, you can have a flag on it and check it from, the controller.

```
public class DatabasePopulationService
{
    public bool IsDatabaseReady { get; private set; }

    public void PopulateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
       //populate in memory db
       IsDatabaseReady  = true;
    }
}

 public class TestController : Controller
 {
      public TestController(DatabasePopulationService svc)
      {
           if (svc.IsDatabaseReady) //do something
           else //do something else
      }
 }
```

Comment: Can you also show how / where / when the call to `PopulateInMemoryDatabase()` is supposed to be made?

Comment: it can be done by implementing an making the DatabasePopulationService implement IHostedService and then registering using the AddHostedService extension method on net core.    https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-1/